# Implement packing/unpacking in an object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class that only contains attributes and I would like packing/unpacking to work on it. What `collections.abc` should I implement to get this behaviour?

```
class Item(object):

    def __init__(self, name, age, gender)
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

a, b, c = Item("Henry", 90, "male")
```

I would like to avoid using a `namedtuple`.

Comment: You can unpack any [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable), so you need to implement `__iter__`.

Comment: That depends on whether you want `__iter__` to `return self` or not - you could just `return iter((self.name, self.age, self.gender))`, for example. It must be *iterable*, but not necessarily *an iterator*.

Comment: Okay thanks I think I got it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can unpack any [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable). This means you need to implement the `__iter__` method, and return an iterator. In your case, this could simply be:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter((self.name, self.age, self.gender))
```

Alternatively you could make your class an [`Iterator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterator), then `__iter__` would `return self` and you'd need to implement `__next__`; this is more work, and probably not worth the effort.

For more information see [What exactly are Python's iterator, iterable, and iteration protocols?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9884132/3001761)

---

Per the question I linked above, you could also implement an iterable with `__getitem__`:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    return (self.name, self.age, self.gender)[index]
```

Comment: For a generic shallow unpacking (which is what you might want) use: `def __iter__(self):  return iter(tuple(getattr(self, field.name) for field in dataclasses.fields(self)))`.

Comment: @AdiShavit that's not so relevant to this answer, which isn't about dataclasses

Answer (score 25):

A better option for unpacking Python 3.7+ dataclasses is as follows:

```py
from dataclasses import astuple, dataclass

@dataclass 
class Item:
    name: str
    age: int
    gender: str

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(astuple(self))

a, b, c = Item("Henry", 90, "male")
```

Comment: the subclassing from `object` is redundant, but otherwise seems pretty legit.

Comment: True--I just copied the example above. Fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, `dataclasses.astuple()` does deep unpacking which is often undesirable for nested structures -- (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51802661/1190077 ).

Comment: For a shallow unpacking (which is what you might want) use:  `def __iter__(self):  return iter(tuple(getattr(self, field.name) for field in dataclasses.fields(self)))`.

Comment: @AdiShavit why make the tuple _then_ the iterator? Just return the generator expression. You could add this as another answer.

Comment: Simpler and faster shallow unpacking `def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__dict__.values())`

Comment: self.__dict__.values() may not work if the dataclass is defined to use slots--a feature added in 3.10.

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

```
Item = collections.namedtuple('Item', ['name', 'age', 'gender'])
```

So this works out of the box:

```
a, b, c = Item("Henry", 90, "male")
```

---

If you're on Python 3.7+, you could also take advantage of [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) which are more powerful. But you would need to explicitly call `astuple`:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Item(object):
    name: str
    age: int
    gender: str

a, b, c = dataclasses.astuple(Item("Henry", 90, "male"))
```

Comment: The named tuple can also be used as an (anonymous) base class, should you want to add other methods to the class. `class Item(collections.namedtuple('Item', ['name', 'age', 'gender'])): ...`

Comment: @chepner That is nice. I also added a similar solution with dataclasses, but they require you to be a bit more explicit

Comment: The question literally says "I would like to avoid using a namedtuple".

Comment: @wim Sigh. I suggested he post the answer here since https://stackoverflow.com/q/59568853/1126841 was closed as a duplicate of this one. Maybe I should reopen that question, and the answer can be posted there?

Comment: @wim I had added a 2nd solution with data classes, so I find it is petty to complain about it. In any case, I was providing a solution to a similar question that was closed instead

Comment: Why not just use the same answer as @jonrsharpe with the dataclass?

Answer (score -2):

You can overload Python's `__new__()` static method, as mentioned in the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> `__new__()` is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types (like int, str, or tuple) to customize instance creation.

So you can achieve a similar behavior by adapting the code like this

```
class Item(object):

    def __new__(self, name, age, gender):
        return (name, age, gender)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a, b, c = Item("Henry", 90, "male")
    print(a,b,c)
    # output -> Henry 90 male
```