# Why is dataclasses.astuple returning a deepcopy of class attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

In the code below the `astuple` function is carrying out a deep copy of a class attribute of the dataclass. Why is it not producing the same result as the function `my_tuple`?

```
import copy
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Demo:
    a_number: int
    a_bool: bool
    classy: 'YOhY'

    def my_tuple(self):
        return self.a_number, self.a_bool, self.classy

class YOhY:
    def __repr__(self):
        return (self.__class__.__qualname__ + f" id={id(self)}")


why = YOhY()
print(why)  # YOhY id=4369078368

demo = Demo(1, True, why)
print(demo)  # Demo(a_number=1, a_bool=True, classy=YOhY id=4369078368)

untrupled = demo.my_tuple()
print(untrupled)  # YOhY id=4369078368

trupled = dataclasses.astuple(demo)
print(trupled)  # YOhY id=4374460064

trupled2 = trupled
print(trupled2)  # YOhY id=4374460064

trupled3 = copy.copy(trupled)
print(trupled3)  # YOhY id=4374460064

trupled4 = copy.deepcopy(trupled)
print(trupled4)  # YOhY id=4374460176
```

**Footnote**

As [Anthony Sottile's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812183/anthony-sottile) excellent response makes clear this is the behavior coded into Python 3.7. Anyone expecting astuple to unpack the same way as collections.namedtuple will need to replace it with a method similar to `Demo.my_tuple`. The following code is less fragile than my_tuple because it will not need modification if the fields of the dataclass are changed. On the other hand it won't work if `__slots__` are in use.

Both versions of the code pose a threat whenever a `__hash__` method is present in the class or its superclasses. See the Python 3.7 documentation for `unsafe_hash` in particular the two paragraphs beginning 'Here are the rules governing implicit creation of a `__hash__()` method'.

```
def unsafe_astuple(self):
    return tuple([self.__dict__[field.name] for field in dataclasses.fields(self)])
```

Comment: At a guess, this is to avoid aliasing issues, so if some code mutates the values in the copied object, the change doesn't reflect in the 'original' object in the dataclass.

Comment: wonder will this API provide an argument so that we don't always deep copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be an [undocumented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.astuple) behaviour of `astuple` (and `asdict` it seems as well).

> #### `dataclasses.astuple(*, tuple_factory=tuple)`
>
> Converts the dataclass `instance` to a tuple (by using the factory function `tuple_factory`). Each dataclass is converted to a tuple of its field values. dataclasses, dicts, lists, and tuples are recursed into.

Here's [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13990745350d9332103b37c2425fa9977716db4b/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1016-L1029):

```
def _asdict_inner(obj, dict_factory):
    if _is_dataclass_instance(obj):
        result = []
        for f in fields(obj):
            value = _asdict_inner(getattr(obj, f.name), dict_factory)
            result.append((f.name, value))
        return dict_factory(result)
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
        return type(obj)(_asdict_inner(v, dict_factory) for v in obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        return type(obj)((_asdict_inner(k, dict_factory), _asdict_inner(v, dict_factory))
                          for k, v in obj.items())
    else:
return copy.deepcopy(obj)
```

The deepcopy here seems intentional, though probably should be documented.

Comment: The behavior *is* documented; it's what the line "dataclasses, dicts, lists, and tuples are recursed into" is referring to.

Comment: @jwodder it would make sense for an implementation from a consistency standpoint to deep copy all of the attributes -- that said it doesn't explicitly state that non-list/non-dict/non-tuples are deep copied.

Comment: it is now documented: "dataclasses, dicts, lists, and tuples are recursed into. Other objects are copied with copy.deepcopy()"