# Have a result be both a class and destructurable as a tuple

Tags: python

I came across a method in Python that returns a class, but can be destructured as if it's a tuple.

How can you define a result of a function to be both an instance of a class AND use destructure assignment as if it's a tuple?

An example where you see this behavior:

```
import scipy.stats as stats

res = stats.ttest_ind(data1, data2)

print(type(res)) # <class 'scipy.stats.stats.Ttest_indResult'>

# One way to assign values is by directly accessing the instance's properties.
p = res.pvalue
t = res.statistic

# A second way is to treat the result as a tuple, and assign to variables directly. But how is this working? 
# We saw above that the type of the result is NOT a tuple but a class. How would Python know the order of the properties here? (It's not like we're destructuring based on named properties)
t, p = stats.ttest_ind(data1, data2)
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837520/implement-packing-unpacking-in-an-object) maybe

Answer (score 2):

[It's](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/dde50595862a4f9cede24b5d1c86935c30f1f88a/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py#L6370) a [named tupl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python)e, which is basically an extension to tuple type in python.

Answer (score 0):

To unpack a data type with `a, b = some_object`, the object on the right side needs to be iterable. A list or tuple works, obviously, but you can make your own class iterable by implementing an `__iter__` method.

For example, the following class would behave consistently with the interface you've shown the `Ttest_indResult` class to have (though it's probably implemented very differently):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, statistic, pvalue):
        self.statistic = statistic    # these attributes are accessible by name
        self.pvalue = pvalue

    def __iter__(self):               # but you can also iterate to get the same values
        yield self.statistic
        yield self.pvalue
```